# Declare dynamic const variable types in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

We are using below line to export const types in reactjs

```
export const TEST_VARIABLE = 'TEST_VALUE'
```

But I want to declare like below

```
var module_name = 'TEST'
export const module_name + 'VARIABLE' = module_name + 'VALUE';
```

I tried many combination but it won't work. For example

```
var module_name = 'TEST'
export const {module_name + 'VARIABLE'} = module_name + 'VALUE';
export const [module_name + 'VARIABLE'] = module_name + 'VALUE';
```

Comment: You can use template literals for it

Comment: You cannot form variable names with string operations, but you *can* form object property names.

Comment: You cannot create variable name dynamically, instead you can try creating object and adding dynamic property

Comment: `var module_name = 'value'; 
    const result = 'just_result'
        var i = 'result'; 

            eval('var ' + module_name + i + '= ' +i + ';'); 

        console.log("value0=" + valueresult); `